# Slack Block-kit Multi_users_select Show only members in the channel

Tags: javascript, java, slack-api, slack-block-kit

```
List<com.slack.api.model.block.LayoutBlock> content = new ArrayList<>(
                asBlocks(
                        input(
                                input -> input.blockId(Resource.ID)
                                        .label(plainText("select Users", true))
                                        .element(
                                                multiUsersSelect(
                                                        ms -> ms.actionId(Resource.ID)
                                                                .placeholder(plainText(pt -> pt.text("users")))))),);
```

These block gives the list of users in the entire workspace but i only need users in the existing channel

https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#users_multi_select

I've tried to get the list of users and use multi static select and send it as options object.

https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#static_multi_select

But here i have construct option object and and pass userName and Id which not feasible